# Monger Missing codec for java.math.Bigdecimal

Tags: mongodb, clojure, monger

Trying to  Insert a Document to Mongo using Monger With a Float/Big Decimal in it

> (mc/insert db "products" {:name "Shirt" :Price 300.00M })

and gets the following Error .

> ERROR compojure.api.exception - Can't find a codec for class java.math.BigDecimal.

The insert works fine when I remove the Price. 
Am I missing any codec dependency or what am I doing wrong ?. Google search did not help much. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If you want help, you really need to post sample code (a minimal case!) along with the error message.

Comment: Had the same issue - it seems to have no easy solution as far as I understand, read [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/clojure-mongodb/alg9b2mfESA/OuztuCGu5bkJ) for details...

Comment: @AlanThompson Edited the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB does not support Java's BigDecimal serialization/deserialization. 
What I ended up doing is creating my own serialization/deserialization using string values.

So the value `10123M` would be stored as the string `bigdec:10123` in MongoDB.

So just create the clojure file `myproject.data.big-decimal` and require it once somewhere in your project:

```
(ns myproject.data.big-decimal
  (:require  [monger.conversion :refer :all]
             [clojure.string :as str]))

(def prefix "bigdec:")
(def prefix-count (count prefix))

(defn big-dec-serialize [value]
  (str prefix value))

(defn big-dec-deserialize [s]
  (if (and (> (count s) prefix-count)
           (= (subs s 0 prefix-count) prefix))
      (try 
        (bigdec (subs s prefix-count (count s)))
        (catch Exception e 
          s))
      s))

(extend-protocol ConvertToDBObject
  java.math.BigDecimal 
  (to-db-object [^java.math.BigDecimal nr]
    (big-dec-serialize nr)))

(extend-protocol ConvertFromDBObject
  String
  (from-db-object [^String input keywordize]
    (big-dec-deserialize input)))
```

As long as you keep these serializations within your app, things will work out ok. If you need other apps to access your db, then they would have to have the same de/serialization functions, so that could become trickier.

Also there is an added overhead for reading every string from your db, it could affect your performance if you have very high db usage, but I think it's negligible in normal cases.